# How to give pagination - First, Last, Next & previous navigation

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I am working on websites pagination and i am using following code.

```
<tr>
    <td class="nex_pre" colspan="3"> <?php
        $query="select * from prosummary";
        $query="select * from prosummary";
        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $pages=ceil($count/10);
        for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++) { ?>
        <a href="productmanager.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <?php echo $i;?></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Output is showing like this :-

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

But i wanna show output like this :-

```
[First] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] . . . . [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [Last]
```

Comment: You have [1]&[14] already why bother to add [First]&[Last]?

Answer (score 0):

Just concat $i with whatever string you need:

Something like:

```
 <a href="productmanager.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php echo $i==1 ? "[FIRST]" : $i==$pages ? "[LAST]" : "[".$i."]";?></a>
                <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check Below Code

```
<tr>
      <td class="nex_pre" colspan="3"> <?php
                $query="select * from prosummary";
                $query="select * from prosummary";
                $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
                $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $pages=ceil($count/10);
                $j=1;
                for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++) {

                    if($pages==1 || $j==1){ ?>
                    <a href="productmanager.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>">First</a>
                    <?php }else if($pages==$i){ ?>
                        <a href="productmanager.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>">Last</a>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <a href="productmanager.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>">  <?php echo $i;?></a>
                    <?php }?>


                <?php $j++; } ?>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I used this code and here is snapshot http://i.imgur.com/VuaKqE5.png  But i wanna show like this http://i.imgur.com/Xh4jN3O.png   when i will click on 9th page then will show like http://i.imgur.com/Xh4jN3O.png

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will work for you

```
<div style="padding: 10px;">
<?php
  $query = "select * from table_name ";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
  echo "<center><a href='index.php?page=1' style='padding:10px;'>".'First Page'."</a>";
  $skipped = false;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)  {
        if ($i < 3 || $total_pages- $i < 3 || abs($page - $i) < 3) {
            if ($skipped)
                echo '<span> ... </span>';
            $skipped = false;
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=" . $i . "' style='padding:5px;'>" . $i . "</a>";
        } else {
            $skipped = true;
        }
    }
  echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages' style='padding:10px;'>".'Last Page'."</a></center>";
?>
```